# Using Eclipse "Play" Button to Debug with Game Services

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I had previously followed instructions to set up a debug keystore that would match my signed export keystore in eclipse and it was working fine (see below for steps I followed). I was able to press play to debug my game with Game Services. It was fantastic. Until a few days ago. I was using it, making updates, redownloading, using it again, and suddenly BAM: it stopped working. I called it quits for the night and in the morning it magically worked again. Then it broke again. I updated eclipse and it worked again. A few more uses and it randomly stopped working again. Now I can't seem to get it to work ever again! I was beating my head on my keyboard for days wondering why I couldn't sign in anymore and I just finally realized it was the whole debugging thing. I did a signed export and it worked like a charm. So how do I get my debugging ability back?!

Steps to use Eclipse Play Button as Signed Export for Game Services:

1. Copy keystore (do not alter original)
2. In command prompt, traverse to the folder containing your copied keystore
3. type: keytool -storepasswd -keystore yourKeystoreCopyFilename
4. It will prompt for old password and new password, make new password "android"
5. type: keytool -keypasswd -keystore yourKeystoreCopyFilename-alias yourCurrentAlias
6. Again, it will prompt for old and new passwords. Make it "android" again.
7. type: keytool -changealias -keystore yourKeystoreCopyFilename-alias yourCurrentAlias -destalias androiddebugkey
8. It will ask for password for authorization to change the file.
9. Now you can select this copy in eclipse as an alternate keystore to be used. Pressing "Run" will install a signed copy of your apk and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I don't think there's a problem with the play button. It was a fluke that my issue didn't occur when doing a signed export rather than using the play button. My device is likely getting locked out due to improperly-handled room operations (i.e. not calling the leave function during onStop() or something).

The above can now at least serve as a step by step process for using the Eclipse Play button for signed export :-).